# Mobile header and menu not working

Tags: magento2, navigation, mobile-menu

I've made a custom header and add some custom blocks there but now the mobile header and toggle navigation does not appear at the breakpoints, only my desktop header. 
Have i overridden it by customising the header? How do I make my custom header only visible in desktop view and to inherit luma's mobile menu in that view?

Answer (score 1):

Oops turns out I had overridden logo.phtml which contains the toggle nav, I hadn't realised.